# Received signal: Segmentation fault (11) while using Rocksdb

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, rocksdb

I am using Rocksdb as database for the program(C++). For one of the use case, I am making a key of following format to store: key=< fix-prefix >< string-type-element >< foo-type >

I am getting the following error while accessing the "string-type-element" piece of data from the key:

```
Received signal: Segmentation fault (11)
```

The piece of code to iterate the stored data is something like:

```
auto prefix = // defined here
auto from = // defined here
auto to = // defined here

std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::Transaction> trans(db_.BeginTransaction(rocksdb::WriteOptions()));

rocksdb::ReadOptions opts;
opts.snapshot = trans->GetSnapshot();
std::unique_ptr<rocksdb::Iterator> iter(trans->GetIterator(opts));

iter->Seek(from);

for (; iter->Valid() && iter->key().compare(to) < 0; iter->Next())
{
    if (iter->key().starts_with(prefix))
    {
        // This line of code is producing the error
        const auto string-type-element = *reinterpret_cast<const string-type*>(iter->key().data() + prefix.size());

        // some stuffs here
    }
}
```

**My Attempt:**

As you can see in the piece of code above that I pointed out the buggy line. As the error is Segmentation fault (11) which usually means attempt to undefined/outside memory location, so my guess is *reinterpret_cast* is not able to deduce the size of "string-type-element" element as std::string is not a fixed size unlike "int" etc and it eventually end up accessing the memory portion it should not access...

I want to ask:

1. If it is actually the case that std::string cannot be extracted from in between of the key because of unknown size, what can we do about it?
2. Could there be any other reason for the issue I mentioned and how to approach it?

Comment: Looks like you need to copy the data from (iter-lkey.data() + size) to the end of the string. At the moment you're trying to dereference a pointer and magically copy the stuff it's pointing to....

Comment: @sashang and what is the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` is a wildly dangerous tool to use and should only be used in extraordinary circumstances, which you don't have here. Look at the std::string constructors and you'll find one that accepts a pointer to a null-terminated character array. It's not clear what the type of `iter->key().data()` is, but if it is a null-terminated string, you could just change the line to:

`const auto string-type {iter->key().data() + prefix.size()};`

to initialize string-type from the part of the data after the prefix.

In your case, `reinterpret_cast` is trying to pretend that the data pointed to is a string object, which is more than just raw bytes of character type, but has other elements to the structure as well.

Comment: You can quickly go through the `rocksdb` database overview to approach this problem